# Create new instance of a project in intellij

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea, instance

There is some configuration in intellij idea that allows me to create more instances of a project, just like there are in Eclipse.
Eclipse has a configuration in Boot Dashboard - Duplicate Config -
and in Debug Configuration - Arguments, you set a new port for the new instances.

Is there a similar way in Intelijj idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can start several instances of the app from IDEA.

1. Edit run/debug configurations in `Run - Edit Configurations...`
2. Then copy your existed app start config

   [image]
3. In new config your can override any property via VM Option section. For example, to set new port add `-Dserver.port=<new_port>`